# Show that $f(x)=f(x+r)$ is a constant function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that for any irrational number $r$, and any real number $x$ we have $f(x)=f(x+r)$. Show that $f$ is a constant function.

---

I am having a hard time proving this.  I know what a constant function is but my brain is stuck.  Solutions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $a$is irrational, then $$f(a)=f(0+a)=f(0).$$
If $a$ is rational, then $\pi-a$ is irrational, so 
$$ f(a)=f(a+(\pi-a))=f(\pi)=f(0).$$